# Android app uses API 31 java 8 instead of installed java 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have generated a react native app and want to use the installed java 11 at source code run time instead of java 8.

In android studio when hovering over react-native-gradle-plugin, it uses java 11 which I installed which java -version in terminal is java 11:

[image]

Source code used to run the app still use API 31 java 8:

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to pack java 11 into android.jar then replace the java 8 in API 31 folder

app/build.gradle:

[image]

SDK:

[image]

App structure:

[image]

Build tools:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> I have generated a react native app and want to use the installed java 11 at source code run time instead of java 8.

Sorry, that is not an option.

> Is it possible to pack java 11 into android.jar then replace the java 8 in API 31 folder?

No, sorry.

Comment: Does that mean Android is current not supporting Java 11 at app runtime?

Comment: @KimMỹ: There is [some support for Java 11 language features](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#java-11), but not Java 11 (or 10 or 9 or some of 8) classes.